# Centering not working for view added in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I have added a subview in my original view in storyboard. I have set height and width of my subView in storyboard and have taken their constraints.

```
    @IBOutlet var childViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var childViewWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

I want to change the center of my subView in viewDidLoad but its not working.

```
   subView.center = parentView.center
   childViewHeightConstraint.constant = 400
   childViewWidthConstraint.constant = 500
```

Also note that i am changing my childViews height and width in viewDidLoad. childViewHeightConstraint and childViewWidthConstraint is working but centering is not working.

Comment: Why haven't you added the centerHorizontally and centervertically constraints in the storyboard itself?

Comment: Because i want to change its center in other place of my code.

Comment: try like this
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                subView.center = parentView.center
   childViewHeightConstraint.constant = 400
   childViewWidthConstraint.constant = 500
            }

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `centerX` and `centerY` constraints of `subView` with the `parentView`, i.e.

```
subView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
subView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist to use `subView.center = parentView.center`, try putting it in viewDidAppear. The parent view is not yet "appear" in viewDidLoad so when you setting the center of subView it is like nothing happened.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    subView.center = parentView.center
}
```

But I think this is not the best solution of how you change the position of the subView, you may consider using center constraint as @PGDev mentioned in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay answer of @dhawal has worked for me.

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { 
subView.center = parentView.center 
childViewHeightConstraint.constant = 400 
childViewWidthConstraint.constant = 500 
}
```